# Why am I getting a Clustered Index Scan when the column is indexed?

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing

So, we have a table, `InventoryListItems`, that has several columns. Because we're going to be looking for rows at times based on a particlar column (`g_list_id`, a foreign key), we have that foreign key column placed into a non-clustered index we'll call `MYINDEX`.

So when I search for data like this:

```
-- fake data for example
DECLARE @ListId uniqueidentifier
SELECT @ListId = '7BCD0E9F-28D9-4F40-BD67-803005179B04' 

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[InventoryListItems]
WHERE [g_list_id] = @ListId
```

I expected that it would use the `MYINDEX` index to find just the needed rows, and then look up the information in those rows.  So not as good as just finding everything we need in the index itself, but still a big win over doing a full scan of the table.

But instead it seems that I'm still getting a clustered index scan. I can't figure out why that would happen.

If I do something like SELECTing only the values in the included columns of the index, it does what I would expect, an index seek, and just pulls everything from the index.

But if I `SELECT *`, why does it just bail on the index and do a scan when it seems like it would still benefit greatly from using it because it's referenced in the WHERE clause?

Comment: These links will help answer your question: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289393/why-would-sql-server-choose-clustered-index-scan-over-non-clustered-one) [Link2](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2007/07/22/did-you-know-forcing-a-nonclustered-index-scan-to-avoid-sorting.aspx) [Link3](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Tipping-Point-Query-Answers.aspx) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing a `SELECT *` and thus you retrieve **all columns**, SQL Server's query optimizer may have decided it's easier and more efficient to just do a clustered index scan - since it needs to go to the clustered index leaf level to get all the columns anyway (and doing a seek first, and then a key lookup to actually get the whole data page, is quite an expensive operation - scan might just be more efficient in this setup).

I'm almost sure if you try

```
SELECT g_list_id
FROM [dbo].[InventoryListItems]
WHERE [g_list_id] = @ListId
```

then there will be an index **seek** instead (since you're only retrieving a single column - not everything).

That's one of the reasons why I would recommend to be extra careful when using `SELECT * ....` - try to avoid it if ever possible.

Comment: In theory, it should do a seek and a key lookup, but it all depends on how wide the table is, whether g_list_id is a primary key or unique, and probably a host of other factors I'm not awake enough to grab.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: true, if the `g_list_id` is returning just a single (or **very few**) rows - but if this matches 10, 20, 50 rows .... then doing all those key lookups will be just too expensive - right?

Comment: @marc_s Yes, that's true. I highlighted that in the penultimate paragraph...but I guess I don't understand why. If there are were million rows in the table, and we were selecting 1, would this still happen, or is this something that the optimizer might pick up, and decide the other way on?

Comment: (Ahh...while I was typing the previous comment @AaronBertrand said what I was thinking...)

Comment: @Beska: if the selectivity is high enough (e.g. you're selecting **few enough** rows from a large dataset), then maybe doing five seeks and five key lookups is going to be cheaper again. You can't really tell - query optimizer uses the statistics to make this call. That's also the reason why those statistics are so crucial and need to be up to date always!

Comment: @marc_s yes that's what I was trying to say with "primary key or unique" - you're right that if it matches more than one row, there is likely going to be a tipping point where seek + lookup is more expensive than just scanning. Where that tipping point is, however, no idea.